# How to create the array with key and value every time?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a array such as  `$animal = array("a" => "horse","b" => "fish")`.
It is the constraint condition  to create one element (key and value) in the array one time,that is to say
in the first time to create the key "a" and value "horse" ,to make `$animal = array("a" => "horse")`,
in the second time to create the key "b" and value "fish",to make `$animal = array("a" => "horse","b" => "fish")`.

I can create `array("horse","fish")` in two times, in the first time to make the array into `array("horse")`,
in the second time to make the array into `array("horse","fish")`.

```
<?php    
    $animal = array();    
    $x2 = "horse";    
    $x4 = "fish";    
    $animal[] = $x2;    
    $animal[] = $x4;    
    print_r($animal);    
?>
```

How to create array("a" => "horse","b" => "fish")  in the same way?

```
<?php    
    $animal = array();    
    $x1 = "a";    
    $x2 = "horse";    
    $x3 = "b";    
    $x4 = "fish";    
    array_keys($animal[]) = $x1;    
    array_values($animal[]) = $x2;    
    array_keys($animal[]) = $x3;    
    array_values($animal[]) = $x4;    
    print_r($animal);
?>
```

How to fix my code to do the job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using [] to push elements into array, you can specify key, if no key is specified, default values are used, therefor:

```
<?php    
    $animal = array();    
    $x1 = "a";    
    $x2 = "horse";    
    $x3 = "b";    
    $x4 = "fish";    
    $animal[$x1] = $x2;    
    $animal[$x3] = $x4;  
    print_r($animal);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x1 = "a";    
$x2 = "horse";    
$x3 = "b";    
$x4 = "fish";    
print_r($animal = array_combine([$x1, $x3], [$x2, $x4]));
```

Result

```
Array (
    [a] => horse
    [b] => fish
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create an array with all alphabet letters using range() function. Then, you can create your items using letters as keys. But remember, you are limited to create many items in your array as letters in the alphabet. Once then, you'll be out of keys.

```
<?php

/* Get all the alphabet letters. They will be your array keys */
$letters = range('a', 'z');

$animal = array();
$animal[$letters[count($animal)]] = "horse";
$animal[$letters[count($animal)]] = "fish";
$animal[$letters[count($animal)]] = "dog";

print_r($animal);
```

That will produce this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => horse
    [b] => fish
    [c] => dog
)
```